# Panels on the front page get invalid $user variable

Tags: 7, panels, caching

I have a Drupal 7 wite where the front page is a Panel. In one of its tiles I have a custom PHP code that prints out the value of `$user->name'. Now the problem is that it usually prints out a different user's name.

Cacheing and memcache is now switched off. Do you have any idea what might cause this problem..?

Comment: Is there any caching on the panel or the panel pane set? Have you added the User as a context to the Panel? Do you use keyword substitution for "$user->name"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got is. Panels have its own caching that was switched on.

Comment: You don't have to turn the caching off, as Pontus says, just change it to be by context and ensure the user is part of the context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.